# Flash player control from javascript outside?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, embed

I am making flash player that suppose to be controlled from outside, from javascript.

I need those methods:
Play/Pause and Volume level

I am stuck with volume level... I tried to add this code:

```
flashMovie.volume = 10;
```

Where flashMovie is flash instance... And it's show **NO ERROR** but it's **NOT WORKING**

I try to make inner AddCall(); and then when it's called to call() from javascript to return sound level.

AS 3:

```
function setthisvolume()
{
        var vlm = ExternalInterface.call('giveMeVolume()');
        this.soundTransform.volume = vlm;
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("setthisvolume", setthisvolume);
```

JS:

```
var soundlevel = 10;

function soundlevelset()
{
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("objswf");
    flashMovie.setthisvolume();

}

function giveMeVolume()
{
    return parseInt(soundlevel);
}
```

But I am getting this error:

**Error calling method on NPObject!**

I even tried with setInterval():

AS 3:

```
function setthisvolume()
{
        var vlm = ExternalInterface.call('giveMeVolume()');
        this.soundTransform.volume = vlm;
}

setInterval(setthisvolume, 1000);
```

JS:

```
var soundlevel = 10;

function giveMeVolume()
{
    return parseInt(soundlevel);
}
```

And it doesn't show any error, but it doesn't work neither...

Did someone work with stuffs like this?

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here...

Thank you!

Comment: Correct code is in my answer... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the parentheses when calling giveMeVolume, by changing this:

```
var vlm = ExternalInterface.call('giveMeVolume()');
```

to this:

```
var vlm = ExternalInterface.call('giveMeVolume');
```

If that doesn't work, try passing the volume directly as an argument/parameter, like this (this is probably a better way to do it):

AS3:

```
function setthisvolume(vlm)
{
        this.soundTransform.volume = vlm;
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("setthisvolume", setthisvolume);
```

JS:

```
var soundlevel = 10;
function soundlevelset()
{
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("objswf");
    flashMovie.setthisvolume(soundlevel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @someone!
This second option worked okay!

Here is working code:

AS3:

```
function setthisvolume(vlm)
{
        this.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(vlm);
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("setthisvolume", setthisvolume);
```

JS:

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
{
  if (window.document[movieName]) 
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName]; 
  }
  else
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }
}

var soundlevel = 0.5;                  // it's 0-1 volume, not 0-100
function soundlevelset()
{
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("objswf");
    flashMovie.setthisvolume(parseFloat(soundlevel));
}
```

When you are using slider each time slider change you need to change soundlevel variable and call soundlevelset();

Hope I helped next one who is starting with this... :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Code looks reasonable.

Check if you allow Flash to communicate with script There is property when you create Flash object - AllowsScriptAccess - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c9b.html .

Check if Falsh is coming from the same domain as HTML page.

For `addCallback` check if you are getting correct Flash object by Id (the way to create Flash is different in IE/FF, so you may be getting the wrong one).

Check if you have correct SWF file - browser may cache older version... I.e. add element on the Flash control that simply shows static number and make sure it matches to latest one.